# Apply a function to each column of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multi-index

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` with two indices levels that looks like this:

```
     col 1  col 2
A 1      1      5
  2      2      3
B 1      2      4
  2      1      4
```

Now I want to calculate a value by `some_function` for each column of each level 0 index. So for each group of:

```
groups = df.groupby(level = 0)
```

Unfortunately my `some_function` only takes 1D data in my case. I found a way to do this but I'm not really happy with my solution since I don't know how to apply it to big dataframes and it feels redundant.

```
df_new=groups.aggregate({"col 1":some_function,"col 2":some_function"})
```

Is there a better way to get to the same result?

Comment: Try `apply`: `groups.apply(lambda g: g.apply(some_function))`

Comment: I think `groups.agg(some_function)` should work per column

Comment: Small trick. If you're unsure of what is passed to you function, test with `print`. For instance `df.agg(print)` will print the columns one after the other, which confirms that the passed data is 1D (Series).

Answer (score 0):

Use `stack` and `groupby`:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=[0, 2]).apply(some_function)
```

Example:

```
>>> df
     col 1  col 2
A 1      1      5
  2      2      3
B 1      2      4
  2      1      4

>>> df.stack()
A  1  col 1    1
      col 2    5
   2  col 1    2
      col 2    3
B  1  col 1    2
      col 2    4
   2  col 1    1
      col 2    4
dtype: int64

>>> list(df.stack().groupby(level=[0, 2]))
[(('A', 'col 1'),  # <- first group
  A  1  col 1    1
     2  col 1    2
  dtype: int64),
 (('A', 'col 2'),  # <- second group
  A  1  col 2    5
     2  col 2    3
  dtype: int64),
 (('B', 'col 1'),  # <- third group
  B  1  col 1    2
     2  col 1    1
  dtype: int64),
 (('B', 'col 2'),  # <- fourth group
  B  1  col 2    4
     2  col 2    4
  dtype: int64)]
```